# Python requests DELETE method with data

Tags: python, request

I try to send `{"id": 190}` with DELETE method in `postman tool`
It's success . But I don't know how to do this with python requests

[image]

Please guide me .

Here is the code :

```
def delete(url, json=None,**kwargs):
    return requests.delete(url, json=None,**kwargs)
```

I try:

`delete(url,json={"id":190})`

But not work got 500 error .

`org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

Comment: remove `json=None` and when calling  the method use `delete(url,{"id":190})`. Finally get the id by `kwargs['id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

data = {"id":190}
data = json.dumps(data)

def delete(url, json=None,**kwargs):
    return requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(data),**kwargs)
```

If you are using requests version 2.4.2 or higher

```
def delete(url, json=None,**kwargs):
        return requests.delete(url, json=data,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the problem. mine is ````return requests.delete(url, json=None,**kwargs)````  It should  ````return requests.delete(url, json=json,**kwargs)````